# A broadcast receiver inside a service isnt working

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, android-alarms, repeatingalarm

I have a receiver inside a service as i need the scheduled alarm to work even when the activity is destroyed. This is what i have done.

```
/**
 * Created by rishabh on 14/2/16.
 */
public class MyService  extends Service {

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int hour=c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int minute=c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(1990, 1, 1, hour, minute);
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");
        String date = sdf.format(calendar.getTime());
        String str=date.charAt(0)+""+date.charAt(1)+""+date.charAt(3)+""+date.charAt(4);
        String LOG_TAG="DevicePolicyAdmin";
        Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Service Started");
        MainActivity.minochaDevicePolicyManager.resetPassword(str, 0);
    }
}
}
```

And to trigger the receiver the scheduling alarm is here

```
    Intent intent3=new Intent(MainActivity.this,MyService.class);
    startService(intent3);
            Intent intent2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyService.MyReceiver.class);
            PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(MainActivity.this, 0, intent2, 0);
            AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, c.getTimeInMillis(), 60 * 1000, pintent);
```

The onReceive method in the MyService class only executes once. why? What could be the issue. Please help

Comment: Is your service registered in AndroidManifest.xml ?

Comment: you forgot to register your `BroadcastReceiver`?

Comment: `
        <service android:name=".MyService"/>
        <receiver android:name=".MyService$MyReceiver"/>
`
this is registered in the manifest

Comment: Did you try giving the service and Receiver in separate classes.Then try calling the service from receiver using startService method().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try moving MyReceiver to an independent file as public class and use this code to start.

```
 Intent intent2 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyReceiver.class);
            PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent2, 0);
            AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, c.getTimeInMillis(), 60 * 1000, pintent);
```

Update 1 :

This may help you -[How to repeat my service using alarm manager?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16352048/how-to-repeat-my-service-using-alarm-manager)

Update 2 : Check this too- [Android - Periodic Background Service - Advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10420358/android-periodic-background-service-advice)

Comment: but how will i trigger the service after each minute?

Comment: Use an AlarmManager with an intent having action "com.xyz.action" (or your action)

Comment: but what filter? my need for the service is completely different and doesnt exactly need an action

Comment: An action is there to trigger a service. Without an action, how can you initiate a service with an implicit intent?

Comment: If you want to trigger a service every minute, using alarm manager with an explicit intent 'new Intent(cintext, YourService.class);' can do the job. No need of any filters of receivers.

Comment: But if you want to trigger a service based on conditions, you need intents with Actions.

Comment: thats what i have done havent i? new intent (MainActivity,Service.class)

Comment: but the trigger is the time! i need it to repeat every 1 minute.

Comment: Try moving the MyReceiver class to an independent file, rather than inside the service

Comment: And  MainActivity.minochaDevicePolicyManager.resetPassword(str, 0); this line will throw exception when activity is destroyed.

Comment: then the receiver will stop working when the activity is destroyed!

Comment: No. It will not. You are confusing between BroadcastManager and BroadcastReceiver.

Comment: And, will you please tell me what you are trying to achieve? Running a service every minute is what you want - in plain words? For that, why r you using a reciever?

Comment: i need the receiver to run even when the activity is destroyed. for that i need a service so that the receiver will run the whole time. When the trigger is set off by the alarm scheduler, it will execute the code inside the onReceive which is IN the service.

Comment: My god! Why can't you run the service directly from the alarm manager? Why are you making thismuch complex?

Comment: Service will run even activity is destroyed.

Comment: yes, but when the service is running already, how is it possible to call the service which is already running

Comment: and where do i put the code what i want to execute?

Comment: Stop the service after execution by stopself!

Comment: Read that link I posted in the answer. Its same purpose as ura

Comment: @AxeManTOBO i added one more link, which will help you directly.

Comment: Please let us kbow whether that helped

Comment: Have you checked the second link?

Comment: The second link is only for when boot is complete right? so i first followed the first link only

Comment: That boot is to rescheduling the AlarmManager automatically after rebooting

Comment: which method do i put my code i want to run? in the service

Comment: OnCreate. Just like an activity

Comment: hey @DevTest. THe service gets created and the code is executed but its not periodic.

Comment: means? not executed in intervals? Paste the code you used in your question

Comment: Fine. And you should check the design guidelines. Else you will encounter such instances again :-)

Don't worry, I learned it the hard way, just like you I used to wrote so convoluted code, and experts here corrected my way :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Although theres a small bug in my app. Could you help me with that? Can we move this discussion to chat?

Comment: Yes. Or you can start a new question, so that you may get better opinions from the seniors :-)

Answer (score 0):

you need to register it in service as follows,

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
  filter.addAction("SOME_ACTION");
  filter.addAction("SOME_OTHER_ACTION");

context.registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
```

Also in onReceive method you need to check for the action of broadcast receiver fired for.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: where do i add this? and what action do i add?

Comment: what exactly you want to achieve in your service so i can answer you in better way.

Comment: the code is there. what i want to do is that the receiver should be on 24/7 and should not be closed when the activity is destroyed

Answer (score 0):

One of your problems is that your getting a service using the intent which use the broadcast receiver. Start changing this:

```
PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(MainActivity.this, 0, intent2, 0);
```

For this:

```
PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(MainActivity.this, 0, intent3, 0);
```

Comment: if i do that whats the point of intent 2. its not doing anything

Comment: If you want to get the broadcast you should use getBroadcast instead of getService